# Ionic 2 streaming media plugin not working on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic2, streaming

I created a live streaming app, i used the streaming media plugin for playing the videos and it works well on android but it doesn't work on iOS.
The video player open successfully but the video not working and no errors appear in the console.

[Link of the plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media/)

```
playVideo(url) {
let options: StreamingVideoOptions = {
  successCallback: () => { console.log('Finished Video') },
  errorCallback: (e) => { console.log('Error: ', e) },
  orientation: 'portrait'
};
this.streamingMedia.playVideo(url, options);
```

}

Comment: pls paste the link for the streaming plugin and ur usage of it in the ques

Comment: The link and the usage has ben added to the question. Thanks

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: @Dhyey Same problem happen with me. video is not woking url is "http://www.youtube.com/embed/uJAWaE11Jf4"

Comment: has anyone able to solve this?

Comment: I am also facing same problem

Comment: Same issue with iOS build, working fine with Android build
(iOS show black screen)

Answer (score 1):

> Use IONIC InAppBrowser instead of StreamingVideoOptions
>
> InAppBrowser Docs
>   -https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/

**Use this code for ios**

```
const browser = this.iab.create(url, '_self');
browser.show;
```

**Use this code for android**

```
streamingMedia.playVideo(url, options);
```